# Why does my map function doesn't work after updated Redux state with react

Tags: redux, react-redux

I'm displaying a list of items from my state store. I want to update this list with an onClick Button. My list is displayed with a map function, at first it works well however but I'm clicking the button I've got the following error `data.map is not a function`. When I running my component without displaying the data list item, everything works fine, state update correctly.

Here is my reducer with my list of Items :

```
var all = [
  {x: 'a', y: 20}, 
  {x: 'b', y: 14}, 
  {x: 'c', y: 12}, 
  {x: 'd', y: 19}, 
  {x: 'e', y: 18}, 
  {x: 'f', y: 15}, 
  {x: 'g', y: 10}, 
  {x: 'h', y: 14}
];

var filtered = [
  {x: 'a', y: 9}, 
  {x: 'b', y: 5}, 
  {x: 'c', y: 6}, 
  {x: 'd', y: 12}, 
  {x: 'e', y: 10}, 
];


const ChartData = (state = all, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'DATA_CHART_ALL':
      return { all: update(state.all, {$set: all})}
    case 'DATA_CHART_FILTER':
        return { all: update(state.filtered, {$set: filtered})}
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

and here is my component :

```
    function DisplayData ({  data, DataSetUpdate }) {
      return (
        <div>
        <ul>
          { data.map((m, i) =>
            <li key={i}>{m.x} - {m.y}</li>
          )}
        </ul>
        <button onClick={DataSetUpdate}>dataSetupdate</button>
        </div>
      );
    }

    const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
        return {
            data: state.ChartData
        };
    };


    const mapDispachToProps = (dispatch) => {
        return {
            DataSetUpdate: () => {dispatch (datachartFilter())},
        };
    };
```

I guess there is something wrong in my component. I think I need to use something like this.props somewhere but I don't know where. I've also try to build a ES6 component `class DisplayData extends React.Component` with a constructor method but with this I don't know how to pass my DataSetUpdate function.

here is the JS bin https://jsbin.com/xocopal/edit?js,console,output

Thanks !

Edit#1 : My JS bin doesn't work because I can't make the immutable libraries works : https://cdnjs.com/libraries/immutable so the update method in my reducer is undefined.

Comment: Can we see the component/container that you send the data and DataSetUpdate from? It should be something like <DisplayData data DataSetUpdate />

Comment: hum... do you mean this ? `const AppChart = connect(mapStateToProps,mapDispachToProps)(DisplayData);
            export default AppChart` ... don't want to share all my code... I don't think it's useful... or Yes ?

Comment: Is that the only place you call DisplayData?

Comment: No then I'm calling AppChart in a basic App component `const App = () => ( <div><AppChart /></div>`. then there is my client.js with the store provider. but I think this part is ok.

Comment: can you put your entire app in a jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net so i can take a look?

Comment: Yep I was doing this here : https://jsbin.com/xocopal/edit?js,console,output

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120259/discussion-between-blackmind-and-simon-breton).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

reducers should just changes the state based on input (always a new state)
if you ever hookup to an API, you would do the calls in your actions and then send the data to your reducer for the update

I think you just need to update your reducer to 
This makes a simpler and cleaner solution

```
        const ChartData = (state = all, action) => {
        switch (action.type) {
          case 'DATA_CHART_ALL':
            return action.data
          case 'DATA_CHART_FILTER':
              return action.data
          default:
            return state;
        }
      };
```

and your action to

```
              function datachartAll() {
                return {
                  type: 'DATA_CHART_ALL',
                  data: all
                };
              }

              function datachartFilter() {
                return {
                  type: 'DATA_CHART_FILTER',
                  data: filtered
                };
              }
```

see https://jsbin.com/vobuduluni/1/edit?js,console,output

Comment: ok so just to make it clear and if that maybe can help someone one day : first I didn't understand that my action had to be connected to my data, not the reducer. I've also didn't understand that my action 'payload' is also defined in my component ! Thanks @blackmind